# Why doesn't Apple Maps find an address that contains a suite letter?

Tags: ios, maps

I live in a duplex, and my address is of the form `<Suite Letter>-<House Number> <Street Name>`. When I search for my address in the new Apple Maps app, it only seems to locate my *street*, dropping the pin at some arbitrary location. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Maps app has trouble parsing some address formats. In my case, the address on my contact card was formatted as in the question: `<Suite Letter>-<House Number>`, with the letter and number joined by a hyphen.

This seems to cause the Maps app to simply ignore the letter/number. Reformatting my address to remove the hyphen (`<Letter> <Number>` or `<Number> <Letter>` both work, but to be precise in my case I moved my suite letter to the second address line) resolved the issue, and I can now type *Home* in the search box, pick my contact info, and get the correct result.

Of course, some streets simply lack detailed geographic data so that Maps doesn't know where each address is along the street. In my case, it was a formatting issue, but in many cases it is simply a lack of detailed data on a block by block basis.

Comment: A-123 seems to be an oddball notation, according to Canada Post's [Addressing Guidelines](http://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/manual/PGaddress-e.asp#1417756). I'm more used to 123A or 4-123. Apple Maps does recognize both as belonging to 123.

Comment: That's a good point - I'd never seen those guidelines before. Thanks! I think I started using A-123 because someone I deal with formatted my address that way, and theirs seemed like the sort of standard I should follow. I prefer the CP guidelines. :)